# how to get data from single json

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

here is my code

```
ng-repeat="item  in records"
{{item.listingname}}
```

i got this error-

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use
>   'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item  in
>   records, Duplicate key: string:i, Duplicate value: i

how to get data from this json

```
[{"position":1,"listingmasterid":"20120","listingname":"Prabhu Traders.","recommended_flag":"advantage-mark","recommended_title":"Verified and Recommended","search_type":"area0-sibling","areamasterid":"148","avgrating":5,"ratingcount":"29","listingphones":"9860435060,9422717367","uniqueid":"145561808456c2f8242e485","countryid":"99","stateid":"1493","cityid":"39","areaid":"148","address":"","address2":"Jalgaon Aurangabad Bypass Road","landmark":"Beside Wheel Alignment ","website":"","mobile":"9860435060","mobile2":"9422717367","stdcode":"","landline1":"","email":"","zipcode":"431112","aboutlisting":"","is_active":"1","is_paid":"1","is_publish":"Y","is_private":"Y","is_verified":"1","totalrrcount":"489","countryname":"India","statename":"Maharashtra","cityname":"Aurangabad (MS)","areaname":"Sillod","url":"http://callme.co.in/en/aurangabad/prabhu-traders-_aUXnAwZE/592656/36818266/39802?kp=2?ut=M","relevance_boolean":"","relevance_natural":""},{"position":2,"listingmasterid":"6795","listingname":"RISHI AGRO","recommended_flag":"freeverified-mark","recommended_title":"Verified and Recommended","search_type":"area0-sibling-fv","areamasterid":"66","avgrating":4,"ratingcount":"1","listingphones":"9322228050,9004049974","uniqueid":"187b38ba-47d7-11e5-966f-7071bcbcf6ed","countryid":"99","stateid":"1493","cityid":"39","areaid":"66","address":"64-A ","address2":"NEW SHANTI NIKETAN COLONY","landmark":" BEHIND AIR TRIMURTI CHOWK","website":"rishibiotech.com","mobile":"9322228050","mobile2":"9004049974","stdcode":"0240","landline1":"","email":"","zipcode":"","aboutlisting":"","is_active":"1","is_paid":"0","is_publish":"Y","is_private":"Y","is_verified":"1","totalrrcount":"38","countryname":"India","statename":"Maharashtra","cityname":"Aurangabad (MS)","areaname":"Jawahar Colony","url":"http://callme.co.in/en/aurangabad/rishi-agro-187b38ba-47d7-11e5-966f-7071bcbcf6ed/592656/36818267/39802?kp=1?ut=M","relevance_boolean":"","relevance_natural":""}]
```

Comment: use [this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting your question

Comment: you can use `angular.toJson` insted of `.stringify` then you can avoid this error

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicates use track by $index

```
<p ng-repeat="item  in records track by $index">{{item.listingname}}</p>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BozTOdQkBJnSdcZXpLy8?p=preview)**

Comment: and get array from localStorage and i want to show in UI with ng-repeat

Comment: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$parse/ueoe?p0=records%20%7C
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13443:12
    at AST.consume (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27388:13)
    at AST.identifier (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27326:22)
    at AST.filter (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27306:58)
    at AST.filterChain (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27174:19)
    at AST.expressionStatement (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27167:62)

Comment: at AST.program (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27159:24)
    at AST.ast (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27146:22)
    at ASTCompiler.compile (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27597:31)
    at Parser.parse (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28484:29) <!-- ngRepeat: item  in records | track by $index -->

Comment: the json file is not valid brother

Comment: yes you need to parse it JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(your data));

Comment: $scope.favot=[];
        
        $scope.favorit=function(list){
             
            $scope.favot.push(list);
           
            console.log("Rakesh---"+JSON.stringify($scope.favot))
            localStorage.setItem("favorit", JSON.stringify($scope.favot));
            }

Comment: this is wrong what you are doing, i need to check the code

Comment: $scope.records = [];  $scope.records=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorit"));

Comment: did you sort it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and replace **MyCtrl** to your controller name

```
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="value in records  track by $index">
        <h1>{{value.listingname}}</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: records |
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$parse/ueoe?p0=records%20%7C
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13443:12
    at AST.consume (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27388:13)
    at AST.identifier (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27326:22)
    at AST.filter (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27306:58)
    at AST.filterChain (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27174:19)

Comment: at AST.expressionStatement (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27167:62)
    at AST.program (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27159:24)
    at AST.ast (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27146:22)
    at ASTCompiler.compile (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:27597:31)
    at Parser.parse (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:28484:29) <!-- ngRepeat: item  in records | track by $index -->

Comment: $scope.favot=[]; $scope.favorit=function(list){ $scope.favot.push(list); console.log("Rakesh---"+JSON.stringify($scope.favot)) localStorage.setItem("favorit", JSON.stringify($scope.favot)); } –

Comment: $scope.records = []; $scope.records=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorit"));